# Bash formatting with awk

Tags: bash, awk, formatting

i am facing difficulties with formatting for bash

This is my existing format, the price is not under the total sales. How can i make it to be place under Total sales? The total sales does not exist in the text file and will only show under certain function. It will not be save into the text file

```
Title  Author   Price  Qty Avail  Qty Sold  Total Sales
-------------------------------------------------------
Book1  Author1  1      1          1
Book2  Author2  2      2          2
$1.00
$4.00
```

Below is my coding

```
echo "" 
column -ts : <(echo Title:Author:Price:Qty Avail:Qty Sold:Total Sales) BookDB.txt | sed "1{p;s/./-/g}"

awk -F : -v search="$1" '        
BEGIN {
count = 0 
}
$1 ~ search {
printf "$%0.2f\n",($3 * $5) 
        ++count
    }
    END {
        printf "%d,records found\n",count
    }
' BookDB.txt | column -t    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F : -v search="$1" '
BEGIN {
count = 0;
print "Title:Author:Price:Qty Avail:Qty Sold:Total Sales"
}
sale = 0
$1 ~ search {
        ++count
    }
    {
    sale = $3 * $5
    printf "%s:$%0.2f\n",$0,sale
    }
    END {
        printf "%d records found for %s\n",count,search
    }
' BookDB.txt | column -ts : | sed "1{p;s/./-/g}"
```